# Ruby on Rails "Form" Inserting to associated tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am building a order management system that contains 2 tables. `:customer` and `:order`. I can destroy, show, and possibly edit. But I can only create for customer and not for order that comes with it. This is the code that I have so far:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
end

class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders
end
```

---

```
def new
    @orders = Order.new
    @customer = Customer.new ({:voornaam => "ABC"})
 end

 def create
    @customer = Customer.new(customer_params)
    if @customer.save
    orders = Order.where(params(order_params))
    @customer.orders << orders
    flash[:notice] = "Subject created successfully"
    redirect_to(:action => 'index')
    else
    render('new') 
  end
end


def customer_params
    #same as using "params[:subject]", expect that it:
    # - raises an error if :subject is not present
    # - allows listed attributes to be mass-assigned
   params.require(:customer).permit(:voornaam, :achternaam)
  end

  private

  def order_params
    #same as using "params[:subject]", expect that it:
    # - raises an error if :subject is not present
    # - allows listed attributes to be mass-assigned
   params.require(:customer).permit(:pakket, :datum_bestelt, :verstuurt, :datum_verstuurt, :tweede_exemplaar, :packettracer_ID)
  end
end
```

### Create Order

```
<%= form_for(:customer, :url=> {:action => 'create'}) do |f| %>

<table summary="subject form fields">
    <tr>
        <th>firstname</th>
        <td><%= f.text_field(:voornaam) %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>lastname</th>
        <td><%= f.text_field(:achternaam) %></td>
    </tr>
    <%= f.fields_for :order do |s| %>
    <tr>
        <th>pakket</th>
        <td><%= s.text_field(:pakket) %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>datum_bestelt</th>
        <td><%= s.text_field(:datum_bestelt) %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>verstuurt</th>
        <td><%= s.text_field(:verstuurt) %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>datum_verstuurt</th>
        <td><%= s.text_field(:datum_verstuurt) %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>tweede_exemplaar</th>
        <td><%= s.text_field(:tweede_exemplaar) %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>packettracer_ID</th>
        <td><%= s.text_field(:packettracer_ID) %></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>

</table>
```

Comment: So, you're trying to create the customer and the order at the same time?  Why is that?  Just trying to understand your work flow on the web site.  Normally the customer already exists and we add an order to the customer.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. The `ruby-on-rails-4` and `ruby-on-rails-3`  tags are for questions that are specific to a certain version of rails. Don't use both.

Comment: @MichaelChaney Yes this is true! however i just want to know if this is possible. Your way is another or perhaps the only option. But if i can do it the way i try to do then i am  almost done with my project.

Comment: @max Ok got it for the next time

Comment: Are you trying to create one order for the customer or many? You used plural but the form looks like only one order?

Comment: If you will create the customer and order together then you need to use "fields_for" within your form.  That allows you to add fields for a different model to the same form, effectively allowing you to have two or more different models there.  You can also combine that with nested params and save the whole thing together (as one answer below shows).  But I doubt that's what you want to do.  What happens if a customer returns?  You surely don't want to create another customer + order in that case.  Typically we separate these functions for that reason.

Answer (score 2):

To create a customer and order in the same request you could use [nested attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html):

```
class Order
  belongs_to :customer
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :customer
end
```

This would let you create a customer by:

```
Order.create(customer_attributes: { voornaam: 'Max' })
```

In a form you would add the inputs like so:

```
<%= form_for(:order) do |f| %> 
  <%= f.fields_for :customer do |cf| %>
    <%= cf.text_field :voornaam %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

And this is how you would whitelist the parameters:

```
def order_params
  params.require(:order)
        .permit(
           :foo, :bar, 
           customer_params: [
             :voornaam,
             # ...
           ]
         )
end
```

However, from a UX perspective it might be better to split this into separate steps.

You may want to consider [having a guest user](http://railscasts.com/episodes/393-guest-user-record) record which you associate the order with until the user has created an account and signed in.

Comment: Also I don't really get why you you would use Dutch attribute names for you model. Use english and [the I18n module](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html) to translate the labels instead.

Answer (score 2):

There might be a problem with this line in your controller :

```
orders = Order.where(params(order_params))
@customer.orders << orders
```

You're actually trying to fetch in the database an order corresponding to your `params`, and to link it to `@customer`. So if you want to create a new order with your `params`, it won't find anything so `orders` is always empty. Then you're appending an empty array to `@customer.orders`.

What you can do instead is :

```
orders = @customer.orders.create(order_params)
```

Comment: His code is correct as long as he saves again after appending the order to `@customer.orders`.  He has much bigger problems than this, though, and getting into the minutiae of various parts of it makes little sense when the basic concepts aren't correct.

Comment: I understand what you're saying. But I also understood that he has succeeded to create a customer but not an order. So I tell him what kind of problems I saw in the way he chose to create an order.

I often try to only answer what I know about, even when it's just a part of a bigger problem.

Comment: His code is correct if he want to link an existing order to a customer. But the form is only sending new fields.